Defining Real Numbers using Cauchy Sequences
I'm trying to define the real number system using Cauchy sequences, but I've encountered some difficulties. We know that the real number system is characterized as a complete Archimedean ordered field. The "Archimedean ordered field" part poses no problem. However, the "Cauchy completeness" aspect seems to require some prior conditions because Cauchy sequences can only be discussed within a defined metric space. (Naturally, the codomain of this metric space's distance function cannot be the real number system, as that's what we're trying to define and can't presuppose its existence.)
We know that when the distance function is the standard metric, we get the real number system we want. But this shouldn't be the only distance function that can define the real numbers. On the other hand, we also know that some distance functions can't define the real numbers (e.g., the discrete metric).
My question is: Before choosing the distance function we'll use, is it possible to determine all sufficient constraints from the Archimedean ordered field? For instance, the codomain of such distance functions must be the Archimedean ordered field itself; these metric spaces must be compatible with the order topology of the Archimedean ordered field. These are the only constraints I've been able to identify so far.
If there are sufficient constraints, we should be able to obtain a class of distance functions with certain properties. Perhaps we could discover their relationship with the standard metric, or maybe the metric spaces they define will all have the same Cauchy sequences.
I'm just spitballing here, and the actual situation might be different. Regardless, I hope to end up with a set of conditions that can be used to derive Dedekind completeness.
In the worst case, if there aren't enough constraints within the Archimedean ordered field to achieve this goal, there should at least be some general principles that can restrict the properties of distance functions, rather than directly specifying something concrete like the standard metric. But these restrictive principles must be inherent properties of the real number system; otherwise, what we define won't be equivalent to the real numbers.
Finally, this discussion doesn't involve the construction of the real number system.

Not sure what you are asking.  The Cauchy sequence method is a standard way to construct the reals, you can easily find good write ups.  Are you saying that you have a problem with those standard constructions?   If so, what problem do you have?

The very first and very last sentences of your post seem to be in contradiction. You are trying to "define" but not to "construct" the real numbers?

@LeeMosher "define" typically means directly stating that real numbers form an ordered field with the least upper bound property, without proving these properties. There are several equivalent ways to define real numbers.
On the other hand, "construct" often involves starting with rational numbers and building real numbers using methods such as Dedekind cuts or equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers. This construction process includes proving that the resulting system forms an ordered field and possesses other characteristic properties of real numbers.

@lulu The standard definition simply states that the real number system is a complete space, assuming the use of the standard metric. However, this raises the question: why do we need to specify the standard metric? If there were no other metrics that could form a system isomorphic to the real numbers besides the standard metric, this question wouldn't arise.

Not following.  Of course there are other metrics we could complete the rationals with respect to. That's how we get $p-$adic fields.  Is that what you are asking?

@lulu However, I'd like to identify metrics that allow the system to be isomorphic to the real numbers, and understand the reasoning behind choosing them. But is there any p for which Qp becomes the field of real numbers?
And I actually don't intend to construct the real numbers starting from the rational numbers.

@user1369469: You may check Ostrowski's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem . Any non-trivial absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$ is equivalent to either the standard absolute value or a $p$-adic absolute value.

@AndreaMori Thank you for the information you've provided. I'm looking it over now. This is new to me. However, in my question, the domain of the distance functions isn't restricted to rational numbers (please refer to my explanation in another reply). Also, I'm wondering if there are any properties in an Archimedean ordered field that would compel us to use only the absolute value to define the distance function?

@use1369469: So your use of "define" is not really a good formal usage in the context of the real numbers. One can define the concept of a complete ordered field, and one can prove that such a beast is unique (up to isomorphism) if it exists, and one can prove that such a beast does indeed exist by constructing it from more elementary principles. I understand that this is all linguistics and does not get to the point of what you are asking, but if you keep this in mind it might help to clarify what you are asking.

Regarding an issue of more mathematical substance, the "completeness" terminology is somewhat ambiguous here. On the one hand, the standard "definition" (in your sense) of the real numbers is that it is a complete ordered field, however the meaning of completeness in that context is not Cauchy completeness. It instead refers to the completeness axiom, which says that every nonempty subset that is bounded above has a least upper bound.

The concept of Cauchy completeness indeed does require the real numbers to already be in your hands. And so, as you seem to have intuited, it makes no sense for Cauchy completeness to be part of the "definition" of the real numbers.

@LeeMosher So, to avoid misunderstanding, I specifically mentioned "Cauchy completeness" in my question to distinguish it from "Dedekind completeness". Furthermore, since the Archimedean property combined with Cauchy completeness can be used to prove the least upper bound property, I can choose to use "Archimedean ordered field" plus "Cauchy completeness" as an alternative definition for real numbers. Under this set of definitions, the least upper bound property can then be viewed as a theorem.

@LeeMosher And I've noticed that if we use the least upper bound property as the definition, the Archimedean property no longer needs to be included as part of the definition (I've been careful about this point in the above comment discussion).

But having done that, how are you going to escape the built-in circularity of your concept of real numbers?

@LeeMosher This might be the issue I've missed out on. Could you explain what kind of problems I might encounter with the definition approach I'm considering using?


"Naturally, the codomain of this metric space's distance function cannot be the real number system, as that's what we're trying to define and can't presuppose its existence."

It is true as you say that you cannot allow the distance function to take real values if you are trying to define the reals in the first place, but there is no need for it to take real values.  The obvious distance function $|q_1-q_2|$ on the rationals $\mathbb Q$ takes only rational values, and this is enough to start talking about Cauchy sequences.

Yes. This is the "standard metric" I just mentioned in the first sentence of the second paragraph : )

So what are you asking exactly?  Your title and first paragraph are misleading.

If you are looking for generalisations you may want to check out uniform spaces.

It looks like you get what I was trying to ask ^^  The standard metric is not the only distance function that can define the real numbers. I want to know if there are certain properties in any Archimedean ordered field that distance functions must fit with.

Oh, and one more thing! When defining the distance function, it's not actually necessary to restrict its codomain to rational numbers. Both its variables and function values can be elements from the entire space. It's just that we can't directly use certain properties of real numbers before addressing the completeness of this space.

The existence of my "answer" may make it seem as though the question has been answered.  If you prefer, I will delete it (but then your comments will be deleted as well).

Perhaps others might need my clarification here before attempting to answer the question. This is because more than one person has had difficulty understanding exactly what I'm asking on the first try. This is also why I need to carefully respond to everyone who's confused. So I'd still like you to keep this content. In any case, thank you for your response. All of this has been a very meaningful discussion : )

Let me try to summarize various points made in the comments and the other answer.
First let me go over the logical underpinnings of the standard concept of the real numbers. In the usual formulation of the axioms for a complete ordered field, the concept of "completeness" refers to the completeness axiom: assuming that one has already axiomatized the concept of an ordered field, the completeness axiom says that a nonempty subset which is bounded above has a least upper bound. The Archimedean property can then be proved as a consequence of these axioms.
As a foundational issue it's also important to know that a complete ordered field can be constructed starting from more elementary mathematical principles. Also, a uniqueness theorem can be proved for complete ordered fields: any two complete ordered fields are isomorphic to each other. All of this, taken together, is what lets us speak of the real numbers.
Once all of those logical niceties have been sorted out to the depths of our desires, we have the real numbers at our disposal. We have them in our hands. We can apply them. This, of course, comprises much of mathematics.
To focus on the application closest to your post, one can apply the real numbers to formulate the axioms for a metric space: a set $X$, equipped with a "distance function" $d : X \times X \to [0,\infty)$ that satisfies a standard set of axioms (known as symmetry, separation, and the triangle inequality). One can also formulate the property of Cauchy completeness of a metric space. One can prove that the real numbers are Cauchy complete with respect to the distance function $|x-y|$.
To turn to some of the issues you bring up in your post, you write "... this shouldn't be the only distance function that can define the real numbers". Let me address this issue in the spirit of my answer, namely that we already have the real numbers in our hands. Then perhaps the question becomes: What kinds of distance functions exist on the real numbers? How are the different choices of distance functions related to the existing structures on the real numbers, i.e. the arithmetic operations and the order operation?
Here is a very simple theorem, which says intuitively that the distance function $|x-y|$ is (almost) the only distance function which is compatible with the operations of arithmetic on $\mathbb R$.

Theorem: Consider a distance function $d : \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to [0,\infty)$. Suppose that $d$ satisfies two conditions:

$d$ is invariant under addition meaning that $d(x+a,y+a)=d(x,y)$ for all $a,x,y \in \mathbb R$.
$d$ scales correctly under scalar mutiplication meaning that $d(ax,ay) = |a| \, d(x,y)$ for all $a,x,y \in \mathbb R$.

Then there exists a constant $c > 0$ such that $d(x,y)=c|x-y|$.
If in addition $d(0,1)=1$ then it follows that $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

In some sense this theorem expresses something that we learn at a tender age: sliding the real number line preserves distances; stretching the real number line increases distance by the stretching factor.
Perhaps this theorem also expresses the "inherent properties" of the distance function $|x-y|$ that you are wondering about?

Regarding this theorem about distance functions, if we replace R in d:R×R→[0,∞) with any Archimedean ordered field (and [0,∞) is a subset of this Archimedean ordered field), does the theorem still hold? (In this case, the constant c in the theorem should also be an element of this Archimedean ordered field.)
